# RESTClient using HTTP Get Request

Tags: java, json, rest, restful-url

I am trying to write a JSON Client which uses HTTP GET method,and I am getting an response of 500.The code I have tried is below,Is there any wrong with the same?The request parameter I am trying to set is entityName=Nila and parentEntity=500000001 as parameters.

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.210.74:9763/services/testEntityService?entityName=Nila&parentEntity=500000001");



        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is on the server side...

Comment: First order of business - does the service that you are connecting to accept application/json? I would suggest that the problems lies on the server side, and not the client side

Answer (score 1):

Its an internal server error yes the problem is on server side.